# can't access site with self-signed cert; what steps do I need to do to recognize their CA chain

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am trying to access a web service over https - it's a site that is same company but not same data center. If I run:

```
 curl --verbose -d '{"client_secret":"123abc", "client_id":"someervice"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://api.anotherdomain.com/token
```

I get:

```
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

By using:

```
# openssl s_client -showcerts -connect api.anotherdomain.com:443
```

I can see they have a self-signed cert. What steps can I take to make sure myserver can access this? I htink I need to add their self-signed cert in PEM format and `update-ca-trust`. What parts of the PEM file do I need to have this work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**Download cert:**

openssl s_client -servername api.anotherdomain.com -connect api.anotherdomain.com:443 > foo.crt

**If you use CentOS:**

yum install ca-certificates

update-ca-trust force-enable

cp foo.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/

update-ca-trust extract

**If you use Debian:**

sudo cp foo.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt

sudo update-ca-certificates